# Graficar partes de los ejes coordenados

Tags: funciones, revisión-de-código, latex, funcion, ecuacion-cuadratica

Estoy intentando graficar la función `f(x)= x^2+x+41`, evidentemente ocupa espacio de forma inconveniente, por lo que sería más práctico mostrar el eje Y desde 38 a 49, para evitar la deformación con la opción yscale.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. ¿Dónde quieres graficar esa función? ¿Algún lenguaje, framework o librería particular? Se necesita más información para poder ayudarte. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega todo lo que haga falta. Puedes leer [mre]. Saludos

Comment: @Arnold Fernández te animo a compartir el código que has intentado hacer. No nos especificas en qué lenguaje de programación estás trabajando.